# FCM push notification does not show banner, only shows on system tray and emits sound

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing out sending some simple notifications as guided [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/kotlin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt) (the official Github quickstart for FCM messaging). It did send a notification to my device correctly, i.e. it did make the notification sound and show up in my system tray, but the notification banner isn't showing. I followed the code provided in the official doc exactly. For reference, here is my code for the `sendNotification` part:

```
private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

How do I make the notification banner appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a notification channel with a **high** importance (`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`). This will have the `urgent` user-visible importance level: `Urgent: Makes a sound and appears as a heads-up notification`. Slightly confusing, yes. You are not doing that, instead you are using `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`, which will only make a sound.

Read [Set the importance level](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance) for more information.

[image]